# Support for orbital-space Quantum Monte Carlo in CASINO?

Tags: electronic-structure, quantum-monte-carlo

Is [CASINO](https://vallico.net/casinoqmc/) code capable of performing orbital-space QMC calculations?

Comment: I'm not sure the CASINO code you linked to is even a QMC code. Did you mean [this CASINO](https://vallico.net/casinoqmc/)? If so, my impression is that it doesn't have auxiliary field QMC, but maybe it does have some other orbital-space formulation? [QMCPACK](https://qmcpack.org/) certainly does have AFQMC though.

Comment: @Anyon your comment is probably enough for an answer at this point. It seems as though QMCPACK only recently (2018) added their orbital space formulation and they dominate the Google search results for this. From skimming the CASINO manual, there seems to be no mention of "orbital space" or "auxiliary field".

Comment: @Tyberius It does DMC and VMC but I'm not 100% sure it can't work in orbital-space.

Comment: @NikeDattani it looks as though the recent answer is from one of the developers.

Comment: @Tyberius I saw that but it says neither yes nor no. I'll ask Pablo Lopez-Rios (one of the main developers) shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CASINO is a continuum quantum Monte Carlo code, allowing you to perform variational and diffusion quantum Monte Carlo.

Best wishes,

Neil.